# SharedSparkSession is not working in Spark MemoryStream scala testing

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I have tried to write Spark MemoryStream Unit test case and SharedSparkSession is not importing in my Test case program.

```
**import org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSparkSession 

class MemoryStreamTest extends AnyFunSuite with SharedSparkSession {
  ....
}**
```

My build.sbt file configuration below

```
**scalaVersion := "2.12.0"
val sparkVersion = "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"**
```

Do I need to add any other dependencies artifact or any sclatest version changes required.

The below program getting import issue for SharedSparkSession file.

```
**import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.{LongOffset, MemoryStream}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSparkSession

class MemoryStreamTest extends AnyFunSuite with SharedSparkSession {

  test("spark structured streaming can read from memory socket") {

    // We can import sql implicits
    implicit val sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext

    import sqlImplicits._

    val events = MemoryStream[String]
    val queryName: String = "calleventaggs"

    // Add events to MemoryStream as if they came from Kafka
    val batch = Seq(
      "this is a value to read",
      "and this is another value"
    )
    val currentOffset = events.addData(batch)

    val streamingQuery = StreamingDataFrames.writeData(events.toDF(), "memory", queryName)

    streamingQuery.processAllAvailable()
    events.commit(currentOffset.asInstanceOf[LongOffset])

    val result: DataFrame = sparkSession.table(queryName)
    result.show

    streamingQuery.awaitTermination(1000L)
    assertResult(batch.size)(result.count)

    val values = result.take(2)
    assertResult(batch(0))(values(0).getString(0))
    assertResult(batch(1))(values(1).getString(0))
  }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SharedSparkSession` is an *internal* test utility for the Apache-Spark project and not accessible through the packages you have provided in your sbt file.

The [ScalaDocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/index.html) do not mention the SharedSparkSession.

You will see that the trait [SharedSparkSession](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/test/SharedSparkSession.scala) extends `SQLTestUtils` which is another testing utility.

For your unit tests it is usually sufficient to just create a local SparkSession.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I didn't see your comments. but it's working fine.. Let me share the code..

Answer (score 0):

See the below working code..

---

---

```
import module.JsValueToString
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat, current_timestamp, date_format, from_json, from_unixtime, from_utc_timestamp, lit, regexp_replace, sha2, struct, to_json, to_utc_timestamp, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.{LongOffset, MemoryStream}
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

class KafkaProducerFlattenerTestCase extends AnyFunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  @transient var spark : SparkSession =_

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("KafkaProducerFlattenerTestCase")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  }
  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    spark.stop()
  }
  test("MemoryStream testcase for Flattener JSON") {
    implicit val sparkSesion: SparkSession = spark
    implicit val ctx = spark.sqlContext
    import sparkSesion.implicits._
    val input = MemoryStream[String]
    val valueDf = input.toDS().selectExpr("CAST(value As STRING)")
    val df2 = (valueDf.select(to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("content")))
    df2.printSchema()
    print(" Before Write Stream")
    val formatName = ("memory")
    val query = df2.writeStream
            .queryName("testCustomSinkBasic")
            .format(formatName)
            .start()
    val jasonContent = readJson()a
    input.addData(jasonContent)
    assert(query.isActive === true)
    query.processAllAvailable()
    assert(query.exception === None)
    print("query....... "+query.runId)
    val eventName = spark.sql("select * from testCustomSinkBasic")
    val actualValString = JsValueToString(eventName)
    println("actualValString..... "+actualValString)
    assert(actualValString === expectValue())
  }
  def readJson(): String ={
    val fileContents = Source.fromFile("src/resources/Json.txt").getLines().mkString
    fileContents
  }
  def expectValue(): String = {
    val expectVal = """{"publishTime":"123","name[0].lastname":"def","name[0].fname":"abc","name[1].lastname":"jkl","name[1].fname":"ghi","lpid":"1234"}"""
    expectVal
  }
}
```

---

Expected class to cover

```
import com.usb.transformation.JsFlattener
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct, to_json}
import play.api.libs.json.{JsObject, JsValue, Json}

object JsValueToString extends Serializable{
  var df3 : String = null
  def apply(eventName : DataFrame): (String) ={
    eventName.foreach(x => {
      val content = x.getAs[String]("content").replace("\\", "")
      val subStr = content.substring(10, content.length()-2)
      println("content ...."+content)
      println("subString "+subStr)
      val str2Json: JsValue = Json.parse(subStr)
      df3 = JsFlattener(str2Json).as[JsObject].toString
      println("df3 Value......"+df3)
    })
    df3
   }
}
```